# Issue in capturing value using plsql trigger

Tags: plsql, triggers

I have created one trigger for table A. When i am trying to make DML changes in table A, the trigger will be fired and it inserts the particular row into AUDITS table.

But when i am trying to make changes on table A through my application (GUI) the changes done in table A. But the trigger doesn't capture one column value in AUDITS table. But I can see the column value in table A. But the AUDITS table's column value is null.

Comment: Did you ever try to debug code you can't see?

Comment: Many people have written such code before. Instead of writing your own, have a look what others have done, for example Connor Mc Donald: https://connor-mcdonald.com/2020/08/04/level-up-your-audit-trigger-game/

Comment: If you don't provide any details, like what your trigger looks like, people will just be guessing.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.